# Qooxdoo - автоматическое обновление, передача  параметров

Tags: ajax, javascript, qooxdoo

Доброго всем время суток!

Осваиваю дальше qooxdoo, столкнулась с очередной задачей: не знаю, как релизовать. Забираю данные с сервера geonames.org и нужно, чтобы со странички уходил запрос в режиме life - то есть если набираю с клавиатуры, новое значение почтового индекса автоматически менялось на значение города.

Мой код:

```
var plzTextfield = new qx.ui.form.TextField(); // создаю форму
    plzTextfield.setLiveUpdate(true); // указываю, что разрешено менять life
var postalcode = plzTextfield.getValue(); //забираю данные
var url = "http://ws.geonames.org/postalCodeSearch"+"JSON?username=***&output=jsonp&country=DE&postalcode="+postalcode; // отправляю данные
```

К сожалению, не работает. В ответе с сервера `postalcode=null` где нужно еще указать, что-то прописать?

В JavaScript эту функцию можно указать так:

```
var url = "http://ws.geonames.org/postalCodeSearch"+"JSON?username=***&output=jsonp&country=DE&postalcode="+escape(postalcode.value);
```

- но в qooxdoo не смогла аналог найти.

Надеюсь, здесь есть любители qooxdoo, кто уже сталкивался с такой ситуацией.

Answer (score 1):

Проблема решена :
нужно было добавить обработчик событий код:

```
plzTextfield.addListener("blur", function(){ sucheOrt()},this);
```

и немного изменить существующий код:

```
function sucheOrt(){
            var url = "http://ws.geonames.org/postalCodeSearchJSON?username=****&output=jsonp&country=DE&postalcode="+escape(plzTextfield.getValue());
```